# SQL Alchemy how to input many to many relationships when using the insert statement and the on_duplicate_key_update

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute an query on an `events` table with a `many-to-many` relationship to a `company` table while handling the up on duplicated key update of MYSQL.

i am using the insert().values() method of inserting since that's the only one that supports the `on_duplicate_key_update` update feature of sqlAlchemy, but i seems there is no way of pushing the relationship value through that.. here is an example :

```py
statement = insert(EventTableClass).values({
    'event_name': 'event1',
    'event_coordinator': 'coordinator.inc'
    'companies' : [1, 2, 3] # this wouldn't work for the fact that a list can't hashed
})
```

My question is how to pass the relationship attribute ? and in case of a duplicated statement, how to merge the 2 companies arrays (the saved one and the new one, while removing duplicates) ?

here is the case when we have duplicated `event_name` :

```py
new_companies = [4, 5, 6] # Primary keys of already inserted company records
duplicated_key_statement = statement.on_duplicate_key_update(
 companies = statement.inserted.companies + new_companies # this doesn't work since as it can't handle arrays
)
```

My next option was to do the update directly on the join table which doesn't work as we don't have info on the just saved event's row data after insertion (`MYSQL` doesn't support `RETURNING` keyword)

```py
# company_event_table is a join table created prior to these statement
# we assume that we didn't put any arrays in the insertion statements, so the execution will go fine

new_event = self.session.execute(duplicated_key_statement)
# the execution returns a **CursorResult** object that can't get any data and whenever i
# try to probe it using new_event.first() it throws this exception : 'This result object 
# does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.'

new_companies = [4, 5, 6]
if new_companies:
   for company in new_companies:
       insert(company_event_table).values({
           'company_id': company,
           'event_id': new_event.eventId # this doesn't work since **CursorResult** doresn't have the eventId attribute
       })
```

I have asked chatGPT (4) and it seems to suggest to use the `session.add()` method of inserting records, but that's not useful for me as i need the duplication statement to be there and the `.add()` method of doing things doesn't have it (i switched to the insert statements as result of the that specifically).